# How to detect duplicate values in array of objects php

Tags: php, wordpress, duplicates

i have this code :

```
 $policy_id = $wpdb->get_results($wpdb->prepare("SELECT meta_value FROM wp_frm_item_metas WHERE field_id=%d AND item_id=%s", 203, $row->id));
```

how i can check is there a duplicate values ?

Comment: Use `GROUPY BY meta_value` and `COUNT(meta_value)`

Comment: Are you trying to eliminate duplicates in your result set, or are you trying to find duplicates (based on some sort of grouping as @Philipp suggested), and take some action on that?   Using a little sub-select or HAVING clause you can find records that have 2 or more instances (duplicates) and ignore the rest.  If i know more about what the end goal is, I'm sure a more focused answer could be arrived at.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than checking for duplicates after retrieving the data, you could ask mysql to give you no duplicates:

```
SELECT DISTINCT meta_value FROM wp_frm_item_metas WHERE field_id=%d AND item_id=%s
```

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple solutions, based on your (not very clear..) needs.

If you just want to know, how often a single meta_value occurs, you could use `GROUP BY meta_value`.

```
SELECT
    meta_value, COUNT(meta_value) as count
FROM wp_frm_item_metas 
WHERE field_id=%d AND item_id=%s
GROUP BY meta_value
```

As result you will get two columns `meta_value` and `count` (containing the count occurences of meta_value)

If you only want `meta_values`, which occur multiple times, you could extend the query with `HAVING`

```
SELECT
    meta_value, COUNT(meta_value) as count
FROM wp_frm_item_metas 
WHERE field_id=%d AND item_id=%s
GROUP BY meta_value
HAVING count(meta_value) > 1
```

And if you just want unique meta_values, you could also use `DISTINCT`, instead of `GROUP BY`

```
SELECT
    DISTINCT meta_value
FROM wp_frm_item_metas 
WHERE field_id=%d AND item_id=%s
```